# How to set a NSView hidden with FadeOut animation in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm hiding a subview from a CustomView element with the following code:

```
[[[theViewcont subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setHidden:TRUE]
```

how can I add a fade animation when hiding this NSView?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the solution [HERE](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CoreAnimation) CocoaDev:CoreAnimation

so when you have something like this to hide your subview:

```
[[[theViewcont subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setAlphaValue:0.0];
```

to animate that action you just should so the following addition:

```
[[[[theViewcont subviews] objectAtIndex:0] animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
```

so there you have the right way to 'fade out' a subview in Cocoa.