# fade in / fade out NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When i was using iPhone/iPad to make apps, i wanted to create fading effect to my UIView's

so i have used the functions down below, it worked, but as i'm making programs for Mac and using NSView instead of UIView the code dont work, could someone please help me out to make it work? please

```
-(void)fadeOut:(UIView*)viewToDissolve 
  withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration   
       andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait
{
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade Out" context:nil];

    // wait for time before begin
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];

    // druation of animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    viewToDissolve.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)fadeIn:(UIView*)viewToFadeIn 
 withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
      andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait
{
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade In" context:nil];

    // wait for time before begin
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];

    // druation of animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    viewToFadeIn.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

/**
 Fade in from fade out
 */
-(void) fadeInFromFadeOut:(UIView*)viewToFadeIn 
             withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    viewToFadeIn.hidden=NO;
    [self fadeOut:viewToFadeIn withDuration:1 andWait:0];
    [self fadeIn:viewToFadeIn withDuration:duration andWait:0];

}
```

**What i did:**

```
-(void)fadeOut:(NSView*)viewToDissolve 
  withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration  
       andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait
{   
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    // Animate alpha fades with half-second duration

    // wait for time before begin
    // [NSAnimationContext setAnimationDelay:wait];

    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:duration];
    [[viewToDissolve animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

    }

-(void)fadeIn:(NSView*)viewToFadeIn 
 withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration         
      andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait
{
    // wait for time before begin
    //[NSAnimationContext setAnimationDelay:wait];

    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    // Animate alpha fades with half-second duration
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:duration];
    [[viewToFadeIn animator] setAlphaValue:1];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}

-(void) fadeInFromFadeOut:(NSView*)viewToFadeIn 
             withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    viewToFadeIn.hidden=NO;
    [self fadeOut:viewToFadeIn withDuration:1 andWait:0];

    [self fadeIn:viewToFadeIn withDuration:duration andWait:0];
}
```

Comment: have a look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908059/how-to-set-a-nsview-hidden-with-fadeout-animation-in-cocoa

Comment: Please see the updated on what i did: i placed: [self fadeInFromFadeOut:test withDuration:0.5 andWait : 0 ];  , but nothing happens...

Comment: So what is happening? Nothing?

Comment: It says: Instance method '-fadeInFromFadeOut:withDuration:andWait:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: Yes it does, it works if it only one

Comment: That probably makes sense since the method you have declared doesn't have the "andWait" part in it

Comment: Yes, because i could not find a way to implant it too, but maybe you can show me?

Comment: If it works with only one animation it probably has to with the fact that the animations run at the end of the run loop when the value has changed back to its "current" value. I'm not 100% sure that it would cause the middle animation not to work though. Just a guess

Comment: If that the case how to fix it?

Comment: If you are calling `fadeInFromFadeOut:withDuration:andWait:` you should be getting an error since the method you declared is called `fadeInFromFadeOut:withDuration:`. The other two methods have the wait part in them (`fadeIn:withDuration:andWait:` and `fadeOut:withDuration:andWait:`). You should probably just change the line where you are calling `fadeInFromFadeOut:withDuration:andWait:` into `fadeInFromFadeOut:withDuration:`

Comment: CHanged it, everything works, but it dont use " fadeOut " only " fadein